# Dagger 2 Constructor Injection not happening before module called

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm learning Dagger 2 and am working on an app. I have a settings module which depends on a settings manager which depends on a shared preferences manager. My problem is that my Settings Module is not getting injected with a settings manager before it itself is being called. That settings manager needs a SharedPrefsManager which is also not being injected anywhere.

What am I doing wrong?

Snippets in order of dependency:

```
@Module
public class SettingsModule {   
    @Inject SettingsManager manager;

    @Provides
    @TimeControl
    int[] provideResetTime(){
        return manager.getResetTime();
    }

    @Provides
    @ThemeControl
    int provideThemeID(){
        return manager.getTheme();
    }
}
```

Depends on Settings Manager:

```
public class SettingsManager{
    private SharedPreferencesManager manager;
    @Inject
    SettingsManager(SharedPreferencesManager manager){
        this.manager = manager;
    }
}
```

Depends on Shared prefs manager:

```
public class SharedPreferencesManager {
    private static SharedPreferencesManager instance = null;
    public static SharedPreferencesManager getInstance(){return instance;}
    String prefsKey = "SHAREDPREFSKEY";
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = null;
    Context applicationContext = null;

    @Inject
    SharedPreferencesManager(@ApplicationContext Context applicationContext){
        this.prefsKey = prefsKey;
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        sharedPrefs = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(prefsKey,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the scope of `SettingsModule`'s component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should have `@Inject` annotations in the modules since they are built to be the ones that create the dependencies and only receive other ones through the object graph or a simple constructor.

---

Here's an example on how you could avoid that @Inject annotation in the Module and the constructor injectors after it.

**SettingsModule.java**

```
@Module
public class SettingsModule {

    @Provides
    @TimeControl
    int[] provideResetTime(SettingsManager manager) {
        return manager.getResetTime();
    }

    @Provides
    @ThemeControl
    int provideThemeID(SettingsManager manager) {
        return manager.getTheme();
    }

    @Provides
    SettingsManager provideSettingsManager(SharedPreferencesManager sharedPreferencesManager) {
        return new SettingsManager(sharedPreferencesManager);
    }

    @Provides
    SharedPreferencesManager provideSharedPreferencesManager(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
        return new SharedPreferencesManager(context);
    }
}
```

**SettingsManager.java**

```
public class SettingsManager {
    private SharedPreferencesManager manager;

    SettingsManager(SharedPreferencesManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }
}
```

**SharedPreferencesManager.java**

```
public class SharedPreferencesManager {
    private static SharedPreferencesManager instance = null;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = null;
    String prefsKey = "SHAREDPREFSKEY";
    Context applicationContext = null;

    SharedPreferencesManager(Context applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        sharedPrefs = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(prefsKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        instance = this;
    }

    public static SharedPreferencesManager getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

With this, you would leave all your injection logic to your Module, and the concrete classes won't have to worry about injecting the classes themselves.

Comment: Slight issue here: In the module where am I getting the manager? I need my SettingsManager to actually provide 2 of those fields. I can see the logic to not using @Inject in modules, but I need to have that field there somehow. I'm still wrapping my head around how all this works, should I be using components to wrap these together somehow?

Comment: Nope, Dagger will automatically build the object graph to use a proper SharedPreferenceManager in this line `provideSettingsManager(SharedPreferencesManager sharedPreferencesManager)`. It will get a `SharedPreferencesManager` by running the method `provideSharedPreferencesManager` whenever you inject any of these dependencies.

Comment: I meant `@Provides
    @TimeControl
    int[] provideResetTime() {
        return manager.getResetTime();
    }`... That relies on the Settings Manager. That's what that manager field is there.

Comment: Oh that's true. Let me edit it the answer really quick, it will receive the manager as an argument.

Comment: Ahhh I see now. Thanks for all the help, still learning exactly how they expect you to use Dagger2.

Comment: I am curious as to why the constructor fields didn't work though. I thought that by using @Inject on those fields it would automatically create them for me.

Comment: I think that they would have worked if the @Inject annotation wasn't in the Module since it created a complex and hard-to-follow object graph

Comment: Yeah I experimented around with it: My main issue was that I was trying to inject into a module. I actually went back to @Inject on constructors and by just passing that argument into the modules I was good to go. Thanks a ton again!

Answer (score 1):

```
@Module
public class SettingsModule {   
    @Inject SettingsManager manager;

    @Provides
    @TimeControl
    int[] provideResetTime(){
        return manager.getResetTime();
    }

    @Provides
    @ThemeControl
    int provideThemeID(){
        return manager.getTheme();
    }
}
```

Should be

```
@Module
public class SettingsModule {   
    @Provides
    @TimeControl
    int[] resetTime(SettingsManager manager) {
        return manager.getResetTime();
    }

    @Provides
    @ThemeControl
    int themeId(SettingsManager manager) {
        return manager.getTheme();
    }
}
```

Beware that your providers aren't scoped, so (AFAIK) a call that obtains `themeId()` and a call that obtains `resetTime()` will most likely create a new `SettingsManager` each time.

So you **might** want to put `@Singleton` on your provided classes.

```
@Singleton
public class SharedPreferencesManager {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = null;
    String prefsKey = "SHAREDPREFSKEY";
    Context applicationContext = null;

    @Inject
    SharedPreferencesManager(Context applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        sharedPrefs = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(prefsKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // why isn' this in a module?
    }
}

@Singleton
public class SettingsManager{
    private SharedPreferencesManager manager;
    @Inject
    SettingsManager(SharedPreferencesManager manager){
        this.manager = manager;
    }
}
```